# Interact with objects through webmethod

Tags: c#, ajax, webmethod

Is it possible to interact with objects on the page the webmethod was executed from?

```
Page A: Content page
Page B: Webmethod page
```

Page A executes webmethod from Page B ->
Can i interact with objects on Page A from the webmethod on Page B?

Comment: I don't completley understand your question but in general you can acccess objects that have been passed from the controller to the view or you can call a ajax action of any controller that will give you the objects.

Comment: @Luke why are you assuming MVC?

Comment: i just guessed... I am not familiar with other than mvc c# web frameworks. And he has c# in his tags

Comment: Could i pass a Repeater object to my webmethod through ajax?

Comment: what is a repeater object?